# Disable ArrowKey Navigation For ComboBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I added a listener to a combo box to disable arrow key navigation(essentially force user to use mouse). However, after scouring the internet I did not find anything promising. Could anyone on here help me solve the problem? Or push me in the right direction?

```
listeners:{
            specialkey: function (combo,e){
                if ((e.getKey() == combo.UP)||(e.getKey() == combo.DOWN)) {
                    e.stopEvent();
                 }
            }
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a giga, tera.. dirty solution to disable keyboard navigation. I am not sure if it will not get some new bugs.
First of all I have removed initEvents method, which is very bad to disable KeyDown combo expand functionality. After that I have removed navigation util class from the boundList: 'Ext.view.BoundListKeyNav'.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        // The data store containing the list of states
        var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
            data: [{
                "abbr": "AL",
                "name": "Alabama"
            }, {
                "abbr": "AK",
                "name": "Alaska"
            }, {
                "abbr": "AZ",
                "name": "Arizona"
            }]
        });

        // Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
        Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
            fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
            store: states,
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'name',
            valueField: 'abbr',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            initEvents: Ext.emptyFn, // This will disable KeyDown combo expand
            listConfig: {
                navigationModel: null // This will disable KeyNavigation in the list
            }
        });
    }
});
```